# Decay of Fourier coefficients sequence

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

If $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is a $2\pi-$ periodic, $C^1$ function, then $k^2a_{k}(f)\to 0$ where $$a_{k}(f)=\frac {1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos kx dx$$ 
are the Fourier coefficients.

I ask if this is true. It's not an exercise but a thought of mine which I struggle to solve (just started to learn Fourier Analysis). Can you find a counterexample?

Comment: By the Lemma of Riemann-Lebesgue, you get $a_k(f) = \hat f(k) \to 0$ for $L^1$-functions. I think a similar result holds for Hölder-continuous functions, but it's been a while since I last looked at fourier transform on $\mathbb T$...

Comment: Grafakos, Classical Fourier Analysis, Theorem 3.2.9 states that
$$|\hat f(k)| (1+|k|) \to 0$$
for $f\in C^1(\mathbb T)$, maybe that's all you get.

Comment: @AlexR,thanks mate,but the problem is that we don't know that $d^{2}f$ exists fot the theorem to hold.

Comment: That's why I wrote $(1+|k|^1)$. This seems to lead to a counter-example if you construct a $C^1$-function wich is _nowhere_ $C^2$.

Comment: @AlexR,ok thanks.i'll try it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Let us start by constructing a $2\pi$ periodic function which is $C^1$ everywhere, but $C^2$ nowhere. Define

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(100^n x)}{2^n}$$

[Since Weierstrass it is known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), that this function is everywhere continuous, but nowhere differentiable.

Therefore the function

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=-\int_0^x g(t) dt=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^x \frac{\sin(100^n t)}{2^n} dt =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\cos(100^n x)}{200^n}-\frac{1}{200^n}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{199}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(100^n x)}{200^n}
\end{align}
$$

is $C^1$ everywhere, but nowhere $C^2$, because $f^\prime(x)=-g(x)$ (both holds by the fundamental theorem of calculus). Note that the interchange of sum and integral is justified, because the series converges absolutely and uniformly in $x$.

Now the Fourier coefficients can be conveniently read off as $a_k=\frac{1}{200^n}$ if $k=100^n$, $n\ge 1$.

Since $(100^{n})^2a_{100^n}=\frac{100^{2n}}{200^n}=50^n\rightarrow\infty$, this is a counterexample to the proposed statement.

*Note:*

$100$ is of course not the smallest number such that this works.